# Getting Data from Vertica with PHP with wrong Encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding, odbc, vertica

I'm trying to get data from Vertica DB using php odbc_connect, I have a problem with Russsian text, so for example instead of getting this text `Уютная` I got an `\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A\x1A`

This is my DNS connection string:

```
 $dsn = "Driver=Vertica;Server={$host};Port={$port};Database={$database};";
 $this->connection = odbc_connect($dsn, $username, $password);
```

And this my /etc/vertica.ini file (app runs in debian Jessie):

```
[Driver]
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
ODBCInstLib = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1
ErrorMessagesPath=/opt/vertica
LogLevel=4
LogPath=/tmp
```

I'm using Vertica ODBC driver 7.2.2-0

Any idea how I can fix it?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solution I found is to wrap the field with URI_PERCENT_ENCODE function (vertica sql function) and in php you do a urldecode.

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434348/need-help-querying-utf8-strings-from-vertica-with-php-odbc-driver/21880603)